# When and how was the magnetic term in the hamiltonian first derived?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, history

The Hamiltonian of a charged particle in a magnetic field is: $$H=\frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{h}{2\pi i}\nabla-qA\right)^2+q\phi$$
Can anybody help me find out when, how and by who was it first derived?

Comment: This may be better suited to the [History of science and math SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Amit I didn't know about that category. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that there is a "first person" to discover this Hamiltonian. It's some like an exercise. By the Lorentz force Law $F=q(E+v\times A)$. This needs to be derived from some lagrangian $L$ that obeys the Euler-Lagrange equation. From that you get $L=T-V=T-qV+q(v\cdot A)$, and then you perform the Legendre transform and got your Hamiltonian. There's no an original process to it. Actually, the expression for Hamiltonian is just the energy, so by definition is the expression you have*. So probably was someone in the Göttingen school, maybe Emmy Noether, who first wrote the Hamiltonian, but it's so natural that i don't think is easy to know with no access to specific archives.

*the hamiltonian you wrote is just the quantum counterpart of the classical, using $p=i\hbar\nabla$, so probably this was first write by Schrodinger or Dirac, in some example of quantum problem.